# Laravel registration via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to make user `registration` process via `ajax` in `laravel`. But I'm unable to do that.

Routes

```
Route::get('/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister')->name('register');
Route::post('/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister')->name('postRegister');
```

HTML form

```
<form action="{{ route('postRegister') }}" method="POST" id="registerForm">
    <h4>REGISTER NOW</h4>
    <hr><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
    <br>
    <input type="number" name="student_id" class="form-control" placeholder="Student ID">
    <br>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address">
    <br>
    <input type="number" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone no">
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose password">
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password">
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
            <button type="submit" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect" id="registerButton"><span id="regLoader" style="display: none"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>&nbsp;</span>
            Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

JS

```
$('#registerForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/register',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function(data){

        },
        error: function(data){

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: My form is not posting.

Comment: you are using a form and an ajax both to the same url, what are actually trying to do? if you want to use ajax then remove the form action part or remove the ajax if you want form to be submitted

Comment: comment out the ajax then form will post

Comment: @Exprator how is that going to solve the problem?

Comment: @Exprator, My form posts successfully without ajax. But I want to do posting my form with ajax. Thats what exactly i want to do.

Comment: ok then remove that url part from action in your form and e.preventdefault from the ajax function. it will work as you need, and do put alert inside the ajax to see if it works or not

Comment: @Exprator he doesn't need to remove that part, javascript is going to handle the form submission, try to `console log` error and success part.

Comment: How do you say that your form is not posting? Try javascript alert inside your success function block, if it is working properly, you will see the alert. If not, see your browser's console for errors, or maybe something is wrong in your backend

Comment: Have you setup csrf field as header somewhere?

Comment: @Chay22, he has already put csrf in the form and he is posting serialized form so it will definitely include csrf token - no need to pass it externally.

Comment: There is a possibility that your html elements are not yet rendered when your jquery code binds the register form with your function. Try putting your js code under `$(document).ready(function() { });`

Comment: @ParthVora as far as I know, csrf token needs to send as header if you're sending such post request via ajax. Not as the form. Take a look at the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: I believe the network tab of your browser says it was a mismatch token or something

Comment: @Chay22, No it is not necessary to send CSRF token into the header. Sending in the body will also work. Try and you will know. The point is you need to send it whether in header or body.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change your code like:

```
jQuery(function($) {
   $('#registerForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

     $.ajax({
          url: $form.attr('action'),
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          dataType: 'json',

         success: function(data){

         },
          error: function(data){

         }
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks perfect.

1) Maybe some form validation goes failed and which prevents data to be stored in the database.

Comment out your server side validations(if you have) and check again.

2) If this didn't work, comment out `dataType: 'json'` in AJAX and check again.

Also, print `console.log()` in your success method of ajax to troubleshoot.

If none of it work, show your controller code.

Thanks

Comment: For hit and trial cases, please try using comments instead of an answer post.

Comment: @RBT, I'm pretty sure that one of this will fix the issue. But still, will keep that in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Can you able to see the xmlhttp request passing to the server through network tab of chrome/mozilla.

```
 If so there is no error in your ajax/front end,
```

2) Before going to route write a anonymous function in the action route to see whether the request comes till the route

```
Route::post('/register', function(Illuminate\Http\Request, $request) {
   dd($request);
});
```

> If You have Auth Routes enabled then there is a possibility 
>       for the request to point RegistrationController inside Auth folder, do a 
>       dd($request) inside the constructor of that controller. hence you can figure it out whether the request is coming there.

3) Try regenerating the APP key (It is just a try if nothing works)

4) Try writing a new post route and call that route in ajax to post the data to the server,if that works the old route which you wrote may overridden by some other route.

Try in the above order , you will somewhere catch the error.